# File Metada not Saved after Update()

Tags: 2013, document-set

We are downloading the Documents from a DocumentSet to a secondary fileRepository system which assigns them a UniqueID.  I then need to update the DocumentSet Items with the new Unique ID per file.  I'm using the below code which does not throw any errors but unfortunately, my Items are not being updated.

```
public static void UpdateNemswithRDIMSNumbers(ClientContext ctx, ListItem Item, List targetList, List<Business.Document> Documents)
    {
        foreach (Business.Document doc in Documents)
        {
            Web web = ctx.Web;
            ListCollection lists = web.Lists;
            var docLib = web.Lists.GetByTitle(SharePointConnector.DocumentLibrary);
            ctx.Load(docLib,
                               d => d.Title,
                               d => d.RootFolder.Name,
                               d => d.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);
            ctx.Load(docLib);

            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            ctx.Load(docLib);
            ctx.Load(docLib.RootFolder);
            ctx.Load(docLib.RootFolder.Folders);
            ctx.Load(docLib.RootFolder.Files);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            FolderCollection fcol = docLib.RootFolder.Folders;

            string s = docLib.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;

            foreach (Folder f in fcol)
            {
                //Find Parent Folder of the Current ITEM
                if ((f.Name).ToLower() == (Item["FileLeafRef"]).ToString().ToLower())
                {
                    ctx.Load(f.Files,
                                     items => items.Include(
                                                            item => item.ListItemAllFields));
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    FileCollection fileCol = f.Files;
                    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in fileCol)
                    {
                        if (doc.Description == (file.ListItemAllFields.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"]).ToString())
                        {
                            file.ListItemAllFields.FieldValues["NDMP_RDIMSDocumentID"] = doc.RDIMSNumber; //<-- The Update to be Made
                            file.ListItemAllFields.Update();
                        }                            
                    }
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                }
            }
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on the line below, i.e. "Filez"

```
List<Document.WithMetaData> filez = new List<Document.WithMetaData>();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's just a leftover from a prior version of the code, I've updated my exmample